# How can I iterate through an object array and place values into a filter?

Tags: javascript, arrays, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am using the kendo ui grid to show data.  I am able to get the filters that I want to use in an object array

```
Object {logic: "and", filters: Array[3]}
filters:Array[3]
0:Object
    field:"CheckDate"
    operator:"gte"
    value:Fri Jan 01 2016 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)
1:Object
    field:"CheckDate"
    operator:"lte"
    value:Tue Jan 31 2017 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)
```

What I can't figure out is how to loop through this array and use the values inside of the filter for kendo grids.  The filter code looks like this:

```
   grid.dataSource.filter({
            logic: "and",
            filters: [
            { field: "EmployeeName", operator: "contains", value: val }
        ]
    });
```

I'd have to make a line for each item in the array to apply the filters.

Comment: So, you are having *several* filters for the same column at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking for a `for ... in` statement? If the order is not important, I would use that.

```
for (var val in yourObject.filters){
   grid.dataSource.filter({
            logic: "and",
            filters: [
            { field: val[0], operator: val[1], value: val[2] }
        ]
    });
};
```

Reference:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in

Answer (score 0):

Javascript `for ... in` has a behavior that is very strange if you are used to write C# or Java code, so I prefer to use [jQuery.each](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) which behaves as I would expect it.

```
$.each(yourObject.filters, function(index, element){
   grid.dataSource.filter({
            logic: "and",
            filters: [
                { field: element[0], operator: element[1], value: element[2] }
            ]
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

the structure of the object `Object {logic: "and", filters: Array[3]}`is actually what kendo datasource expects to do filtering. however, to do this manually, you could try something as follows,

```
var generateFilterArray = function (yourFilterObject) {
    var filters = []
    for (var i = 0; i < yourFilterObject.filters.length; i++) {
            filters.push({
                field: yourFilterObject.filters[i].field,
                operator: yourFilterObject.filters[i].operator,
                value: yourFilterObject.filters[i].value
            });            
    }

    return {
        logic: yourFilterObject.logic,
        filters: filters
    };
}

grid.dataSource.filter(generateFilterArray(yourFilterObject))
```

Finally, remember to not call grid.dataSource.filter() inside a loop as will call the remote endpoint multiple times, so always create the filters object first and then apply it as done above